# Is there a way to hide the main menu bar in one of the components and add a specific new navbar just for that component?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am creating an Angular 6 website where I want to hide my navbar in one of the components and display a different side nav bar in that component.

I tried googling about it but most solutions have a navbar that persists throughout all components. I don't want to duplicate HTML code across all component files is possible.

Comment: to help you further. Do you have sample code? or image you want to create?

Comment: I am not allowed to share code but in summary I have an angular project with a navbar implemented using menu-container in the app.component.html file.

Comment: can you try to create a sample? here's follow this link I'm happy to help you :)
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpjeli](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpjeli)